# how to update Json code, not working code

Tags: mongodb

Can you please suggest how to resolve the error:

```
{ "serverUsed" : "plv12131.pvi.ntt.com:32414" , "operationTime" : { "$ts" : 15217531985 , "$inc" : 1} , "ok" : 0.0 , 
"errmsg" : "not authorized on BILLINIG to execute command { $eval: \"Script_1231_15753184612()\", args: [], $db: \"BILLINIG\" }" , "code" : 13 , 
"codeName" : "Unauthorized" , "$clusterTime" : 
{ "clusterTime" : { "$ts" : 15217531985 , "$inc" : 1} , "signature" : { "hash" : <Binary Data> , "keyId" : 67856920730276}}}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? It looks like you are trying to run a custom javascript and you don't have permission to do so. Maybe you should provide the code that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to user permission. The user with which you have logged in does not have permission to access the collection.
You will have to grant r/w access to the users using grantRolesToUser

> db.grantRolesToUser(
>      "username",
>      [ "readWrite" , { role: "read", db: "BILLINIG" } ]
>   )

Here's the manual which explains the procedure. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/